# Swift calling completion handler in from another file fails

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I am calling a funciton with completio=n handler from one calss to another class

Called class:

```
class PVClass
{

var avgMonthlyAcKw:Double = 0.0

var jsonString:String!

func estimateMonthlyACkW (areaSqFt:Float, completion: @escaping(Double) -> () ){

    var capacityStr:String = ""

    let estimatedCapacity = Float(areaSqFt/66.0)
    capacityStr = String(format: "%.2f", estimatedCapacity)

    // Build some Url string
    var urlString:String = "https://developer.nrel.gov/"
    urlString.append("&system_capacity=")
    urlString.append(capacityStr)

    let pvURL = URL(string: urlString)
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: pvURL!) { data, response, error in
        do {

            let _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
            self.jsonString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
            print("JSON String:\(String(describing: self.jsonString))")

            if self.jsonString != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(PVClass.Top.self, from: data!)

                // do some parsing here
                var totalAcKw: Double = 0.0
                let cnt2: Int = (jsonData.Outputs?.ACMonthly.count)!
                for i in 0..<(cnt2-1) {
                    totalAcKw = totalAcKw + (jsonData.Outputs?.ACMonthly[i])!
                }
                self.avgMonthlyAcKw = Double(totalAcKw)/Double(cnt2)

                // prints value
                print("updated estimate: ", self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
            }

        } catch {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
    completion(self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
}
```

Calling Class:

```
 func estimate() {
  var estimatedSolarkWh:Double = 0.0
 let aPVClass = PVClass()
aPVClass.estimateMonthlyACkW(areaSqFt: 100.0,  completion: { (monthlyAckW) -> Void in

           estimatedSolarkWh = monthlyAckW
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
       })
return 
}
}
```

When I call the function estimate() the estimateMonthlyACkW function in the other PVClass is executed but it returns after the calling estimate() function is executed. So even though in the called function the URLsession is executed, json is parsed, and value is printed correctly - the value never gets gets transferred to the completion handler and the value never comes back to calling class. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `completion(self.avgMonthlyAcKw)` just after print statement like below:

```
   // prints value
   print("updated estimate: ", self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
   completion(self.avgMonthlyAcKw)
```

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: Updated comment: I did that the completion handler gets called I capture the return value in var estimatedSolarkWh. I make the assignment from the var estimatedSolarkWh to the UI, but the UI does not get updated . How to force the UI refresh based on the captured value?

Comment: Add UI stuff in DispatchQueue.main.async{ }

Comment: Modified code still fails. DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
  guard case self = self else {
                    return }
print("monthlyAckW: ", monthlyAckW)
self?.estimatedSolarkWh = Int(monthlyAckW * Double((12)/365 * (self?.numDays)!))
print("estimatedSolarkWh: ", self?.estimatedSolarkWh ?? 0)
guard let val = self?.estimatedSolarkWh  else { return }
 print("val: ", val)
self?.estimatedSolarkWhLabel.text = String(val)
self?.view.setNeedsDisplay()}
        })

Comment: monthlyAckW has the right value. assigned the value to self?.estimatedSolarkWh but self?.estimatedSolarkWh  is '0', value never gets transferred to the current class

Comment: @vrao Could you please accept this answer and other question for UI issue? As completion issue is resolved.

Comment: Ok I will accept, but the value needs to be pulled back into the calling class.